# how to use overscroll functionality for listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-overscoll

Android's new Overscroll functionality introduced in Gingerbread and discovered some more interesting things. 
The functionality to make a a view scroll beyond its limits and then bounce back (almost exactly like iOS) is sort of built into the framework, but just hidden.

> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dOyWCDhlxv8&feature=player_embedded

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can try this it give. you the solution for your problem.

```
scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scr);
    contentView = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.r2);
    scrollView.setOnTouchListener(new ScrollPager(scrollView, contentView));
    scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            scrollView.scrollTo(0, contentView.getPaddingTop());
        }
    });
```

for this you need the scroolerPager Class. get it here,

```
  public class ScrollPager implements OnTouchListener
public ScrollPager(ScrollView aScrollView, ViewGroup aContentView)
    {
        mScrollView = aScrollView;
        mContentView = aContentView;
        scroller = new Scroller(mScrollView.getContext(), new OvershootInterpolator());
        task = new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                scroller.computeScrollOffset();
                mScrollView.scrollTo(0, scroller.getCurrY());

                if (!scroller.isFinished())
                {
                    mScrollView.post(this);
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: At least spend a bare minimum of time and effort before posting... This snippet looks like it's been coded in normal notepad whitout taking the effort to reread it

Comment: @YogGuru do you know how can i make it work for listView (or gridView, or anything that extends from adapterView) ?

Answer (score 9):

According to the android developers visit the following link.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setOverScrollMode(int)

the doc says you have to use following method.

```
public void setOverScrollMode (int mode)
```