# How to enable ListView overscroll in HTC One X (may be all htc devices)?

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview in my app, and in my Xoom, and Galaxy S2, you get the normal glow effect when you overscroll. But in HTC One X, it doesn't show any overscroll behaviour. All the HTC apps have an accordion style overscroll behaviour. Do they use some custom listview?

In any case, how do I show some sort of overscroll effect in HTC phones? Also, is there some  ListView class out there, that implements overscroll effects on all phones (doesn't have to be the same effect).

Some Context:

- The phones are on Android 4.0.3, and Xoom is on 4.0.4.
- The app is using the Holo Light theme.
- The min/target API level (as well as the Project API level) is set to 15.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803195/how-to-use-overscroll-functionality-for-listview), looks like it could be what you are looking for.

Comment: may be worth using one of the DeviceDefault themes?

Comment: cheers, but no overscroll even with the DeviceDefault theme.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of the scroll view on the HTC One X is device depended. You can not simply disable it on the default theme. You can set the Holo theme for your application to get the default behavior though.

Comment: I'm not trying to disable the overscroll behaviour. On the contrary, I'm trying to get the phone to show some overscroll behaviour. The thing is that the standard ListView doesn't show any overscroll effect in the One X. However, all HTC created apps on the phone do have overscroll (i.e. the accordion overscroll). I've added some notes to my question, to give it a bit more context.